Install LibreOffice on AWS Python 3.9 Image base
My Image: public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9 (I only use it because this one has yum in it)
Docker File:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

# Install Mono runtime
RUN rpm --import https://download.mono-project.com/repo/xamarin.gpg && \
    curl https://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos7-stable.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mono-centos7-stable.repo && \
    yum install -y mono-complete && yum clean all

RUN yum install -y libreoffice && yum clean all

anyway, I dont have a yum repository for libreoffice.
If anyone has done it I would like to find a solution

You'll can do something like this to download it and install it.
